# UNION in mysqli prepared statement not returning only one value not two

Tags: php, mysqli

php

```
$wall_id = 5;

    $pull_adj_id = $connectDB->prepare("(SELECT walls.wall_id FROM walls WHERE 
                       walls.wall_id > ? ORDER BY walls.wall_id ASC LIMIT 1)
                       UNION
                       (SELECT walls.wall_id FROM walls WHERE 
                       walls.wall_id < ? ORDER BY walls.wall_id DESC LIMIT 1);");
    $pull_adj_ids->bind_param('ii', $wall_id, $wall_id);
    $pull_adj_ids->execute();
    $adj_result     = $pull_adj_ids->get_result();
    $adj_data       = $adj_result->fetch_array();
    print_r($adj_data);
```

Ouput: `Array ( [0] => 5 [wall_id] => 5 )`

In relation to my previous question, I trying to build my query to pull both the greater than and less than ids from the table but the query is return only one value. But when I try to run the very same query in phpMyAdmin it gives `6` and `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns 2 rows while you are fetching only one

Comment: shouldn't `fetch_array` store all results to `$adj_data`?

Comment: shouldn't you learn basic functions usage from some manual first?

Answer (score 0):

you have to loop your results.

try this

```
$pull_adj_ids->execute();
$pull_adj_ids->store_result();
$adj_result     = $pull_adj_ids->bind_result($wall_id); 
while ($adj_data = $adj_result->fetch()){
     echo $wall_id.'<br />';

  }
```

Comment: got it! the problem was print I guess. used `$adj_data = $adj_result->fetch_array()`.

Comment: seems like they become two arrays, how can I store the two values to one array?

Comment: what result you got ?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => 75 [article_id] => 75 ) Array ( [0] => 73 [article_id] => 73 )` this result, the `current_id` is `74`.

Comment: `Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object` error.